# What does 'No such name' mean in DNS?

Tags: networking, dns, nslookup

So i'm currently using Wireshark to investigate DNS traffic. In the command prompt, i am running the query `nslookup` to lookup a domain. In wireshark i am getting the following response:

```
Flags: 0x8183 Standard query response, No such name
    1... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a response
    .000 0... .... .... = Opcode: Standard query (0)
    .... .0.. .... .... = Authoritative: Server is not an authority for domain
    .... ..0. .... .... = Truncated: Message is not truncated
    .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
    .... .... 1... .... = Recursion available: Server can do recursive queries
    .... .... .0.. .... = Z: reserved (0)
    .... .... ..0. .... = Answer authenticated: Answer/authority portion was not authenticated by the server
    .... .... ...0 .... = Non-authenticated data: Unacceptable
    .... .... .... 0011 = Reply code: No such name (3)
```

What exactly does 'No such name' mean and why is it being displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the description of NXDOMAIN in RFC 1035 section 4.1.1:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4.1.1

```
            3               Name Error - Meaningful only for
                            responses from an authoritative name
                            server, this code signifies that the
                            domain name referenced in the query does
                            not exist.
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks very much

Comment: You can access this property by using dns.flags.rcode in wireshark